# SAS plots add auto figure number to title or footnote

Tags: plot, title, sas, footnotes

Hi I am ploting some data using BY GROUP option, and saving each plot to a separate file. I want to add an auto figure number to each plot title or footnote.

Lets say I have three BY GROUP variable levels, so i will have 3 plots saved to three files. I want to add either titles or footnotes of:

```
title "Figure 01. Plot of #byval"; or footnote "Figure 01. Plot of #byval"; 
title "Figure 02. Plot of #byval"; or footnote "Figure 02. Plot of #byval"; 
title "Figure 03. Plot of #byval"; or footnote "Figure 03. Plot of #byval";
```

Here i added 01, 02 and 03 manually but I want to automate it so that I could give a start value and it automatically increment by 1, until the last level of BY GROUP variable.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have two BY variables where the first BY variable is "01", "02" etc, and then use:

```
title "Figure #byval1. Plot of #byval2";
```

Answer (score 1):

this could be accomplished by macro. The follows is an example.

```
    %macro bygraph(dset=,byvar=);

     %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&byvar));
     %let byvari=%sysfunc(scan(&byvar,&i));
       proc sort data=&dset; 
        by &byvari;
       run;

      ods rtf file="plot&i..rtf" startpage=no; 
/*output,modify as you need.the graph will be stored to plot1.rtf, plot2.rtf... */
       proc plot data=&dset;
        by &byvari;
        plot .... ;  /* your plot statements */
        title "Figure &i Plot of &byvari"; 
       run;
       quit;
      ods rtf close;
     %end;

     %mend;

    /* run macro, fill in data set, byvars (separated by blanks) as parameters */
    %bygraph(dset=dataset, byvar=var1 var2 var3); run;
```